# ERROR : Can't find PInvoke DLL 'sqlceme35.dll'

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I use The PDA  Honeywell Dolphin 6500 for inventory management with XL Tms software ..

I get this ERROR when launching the application on the device ->

```
Can't connect to database .. 

Can't find PInvoke DLL `sqlceme35.dll`
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install SQL Server Compact on the target.  That includes not just System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll, but all of the native DLLs as well.

This means you should also be deploying `sqlceca35.dll`, `sqlceme35.dll`, `sqlceqp35.dll`, `sqlcese35.dll`, and probably `sqlcecompact35.dll`, `sqlceer35en.dll` and `sqlceoledb35.dll` as well.

Comment: And it can be found on MS website: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8831 (for the SP2 version, that is to say 3.5.8080)